# api not fetching when it requires authorization token

Tags: reactjs, axios, backend, fetch-api

```
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState({ member: [] });

            const getDetail = async () => {
                try {
                    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
                    // console.log(token);
                    const decodedToken = jwtDecode(token);
                    // console.log('Decoded token is ', decodedToken);
                    if (!token) {
                        console.log('token not found');
                        return;
                    }

                    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/student/detail`, {
                        method: 'GET',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                            authorization: `${token}`,
                        },
                    });

                    if (!response.ok) {
                        console.log('error fetching detail', response);
                    }

                    const json = await response.data;
                    // console.log('json is ', json)
                    setUserData(json);
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log('error is ', err);
                }
            }

        useEffect(() => {
        getDetail();
    }, []);
```

I'm getting error in fetching data from api's that require authorization token ... the api's that don't require authorization token are working just fine but the one that requires authorization token is not working..

I'm getting this error in console

I've tried using axios but than it says axiosError
[image]

Comment: OK, so what's the matter? You haven't got the Token, and it returns an error, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

```
 const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/student/detail', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`, // Set the Authorization header with the token
    },
  });
```

Make sure you prefix the token with "Bearer" if that's the expected format by your server.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to break at this line

```html
const decodedToken = jwtDecode(token);
```

This causes the catch block to be fired. This is because you you're passing undefined as token to the `jwtDecode` method and therefore, nothing to decode.

You should create an helper function you're able to import to get the token using `try - catch`. This way, you are able to catch the error immediately.

```html
export const getDecodedToken = (token: string) => {
  if (!token) return null;
  try {
    return jwtDecode(token);
  } catch (error) {
    return {};
  }
};
```

There's also nowhere in your code block you're using the `decodedToken`. So you should be fine without that line since you're checking to run the rest of the function only if there's a token.